# Configurating JOOMLA's e-mail notification for new account

Tags: joomla1.5

I'm using Joomla 1.5 to create a local site for my office. The site will be accessed locally via intranet, and my PC will be the localhost for the site.

I'm using a Login pluggin, so that anyone who wanted to enter the site should create an account. 
In JOOMLA, all user who created their account for the first time will receive a notification e-mail like :

> "Hello pras,
>
> You have been added as a User to Information Center by an
>   Administrator.
>
> This e-mail contains your username and password to log in to
>   ***http://localhost/yaddayadda/***
>
> Username: hadisuryo.prasetio Password: xxxx
>
> Please do not respond to this message as it is automatically generated
>   and is for information purposes only."

but if the user click the URL in the mail, which is, "**localhost/yaddayadda/**" they will not be directed to my site, but to their own PC's localhost....

My question is : How can I Modified the e-mail or the site configuration so that the URL will not be "localhost/yaddayadda/" anymore, but will be "**(My-IP address)/yaddayadda**"

I'm not going to host my site to a web hosting service, just using my PC as a host.

I've been trying to trace on each config and .ini files...it seems that i have to do something with the "JURI" function or the "$mosConfig_live_site" on the `backlink.php` file

```
$mosConfig_absolute_path = JPATH_SITE;
$mosConfig_live_site = JURI :: base();
$url_array = explode('/', $_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);
```

Can anyone give me assistance ?

Answer (score 0):

actually what the joomla does it takes the value as $_SERVER for the host so what you have to do u just append "/yaddayadda" at the email template of the joomla

Answer (score 0):

You could edit:

%SITE_ROOT%/administrator/language/en-GB.com_users.ini at around LINE 28, which reads

*NEW_USER_MESSAGE=Hello %s,\n\n\nYou have been added as a User to %s by an Administrator.\n\nThis e-mail contains your username and password to log in to %s\n\nUsername: %s\nPassword: %s\n\n\nPlease do not respond to this message as it is automatically generated and is for information purposes only.*

**Be careful with the '%s' variable** as it appears to insert different values in each instance. First instance renders their NAME, second SITE NAME, third one is the USER NAME, etc, etc.

-Dennis

Answer (score 0):

You can find those values in `root/components/com_users/models/registration.php` on line `88`. It appears it pulls it out of the array that is being created their.